# Need to copy flink-hadoop-compatibility-2.10 jar explicitly to ${FLINK-HOME}/lib location on EMR cluster

Tags: maven, hadoop, apache-flink

I am currently working on an Flink application that uses some of the Hadoop dependencies to write the data to S3 location. On local environment it is working fine, however when I deploy this Flink application on EMR cluster it throws an exception related to compatibility issue.

The error message that I am getting is

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load the TypeInformation for the class 'org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable'. You may be missing the 'flink-hadoop-compatibility' dependency.
        at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TypeExtractor.createHadoopWritableTypeInfo(TypeExtractor.java:2025)
        at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TypeExtractor.privateGetForClass(TypeExtractor.java:1649)
        at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TypeExtractor.privateGetForClass(TypeExtractor.java:1591)
        at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TypeExtractor.createTypeInfoWithTypeHierarchy(TypeExtractor.java:778)  ....`

I have included the maven dependency of `flink-hadoop-compatibility-2.10` jar in POM dependency. But it is not detecting it. The Flink version I am using is 1.2.0

However, when I explicitly copy the compatibility JAR to the `${FLINK-HOME}/lib` location, I am not getting any exception and able to run the Flink application successfully.

---

Is there any way that we can use, so that without deploying the JAR file to `${FLINK-HOME}/lib` we can run the application?

**OR**

What modifications required in POM dependencies, so that the application will detect it and it is not required to copy the compatibility JAR to flink-home/lib location?

Comment: Answer depends what initial exception actually says

Comment: @cricket_007 Here is the error message that I am getting java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load the TypeInformation for the class 'org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable'. You may be missing the 'flink-hadoop-compatibility' dependency.
        at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TypeExtractor.createHadoopWritableTypeInfo(TypeExtractor.java:2025)

Comment: Also the Flink version that I am using is 1.2.0

Comment: Have you tried making an uber/shaded  jar for your Flink application that includes that library?

Comment: @cricket_007 yes I have the maven shaded plugin configured in the POM, that includes the flink-hadoop-compatibility jar while creating the shaded jar. Also as per the link "http://apache-flink-user-mailing-list-archive.2336050.n4.nabble.com/hadoopcompatibility-not-in-dist-td12552.html" that suggest to add flink-shaded-hadoop2 dependency in POM, I found that this jar also getting included into the shaded jar.

Comment: When you shade the jar are you changing the package names of the classes?

Comment: @ilooner while creating the shaded JAR I am not changing the package names. In the shaded configuration we are providing the main full qualified class name.

Comment: Tried to get more details about the JAR deployment. I think, with the current version of Apache Flink (1.2.0), it is  required to deploy the flink-hadoop-compatibility JAR to ${FLINK-HOME}/lib/ folder. The below link discuss about same. http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/flink-user/201704.mbox/%3C138271ec-02c3-7549-99d5-7e73b978b9d5@firma.seznam.cz%3E

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking into various posts and experimenting with POM files, I think with current version of `Apache Flink (1.2.0)` it is required to copy (deploy) the JAR file to `${FLINK-HOME}/lib` location.

Answer (score 2):

```java
package org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils;

public class TypeExtractor {

    /** The name of the class representing Hadoop's writable */
    private static final String HADOOP_WRITABLE_CLASS = "org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable";
    private static final String HADOOP_WRITABLE_TYPEINFO_CLASS = "org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.WritableTypeInfo";


    // visible for testing
    public static <T> TypeInformation<T> createHadoopWritableTypeInfo(Class<T> clazz) {
        checkNotNull(clazz);

        Class<?> typeInfoClass;
        try {
            typeInfoClass = Class.forName(HADOOP_WRITABLE_TYPEINFO_CLASS, false, TypeExtractor.class.getClassLoader());
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not load the TypeInformation for the class '"
                    + HADOOP_WRITABLE_CLASS + "'. You may be missing the 'flink-hadoop-compatibility' dependency.");
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

This is because `org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable` is mean to be loaded by TypeExtractor.class.getClassLoader() which is `AppClassLoader`, and the submited flink jar is loaded by `ParentFirstClassLoader`, which is the child of `AppClassLoader`, so `AppClassLoader` can not load `org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable` from your flink jar.

I'm not sure if it's a bug, change to classLoader to `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()` will make it work without copy the flink-hadoop-compatibility jar file to ${FLINK-HOME}/lib location.